# Xml in python with unbalanced/uneven elements/tags

Tags: python, xml, xml-parsing

I have a an xml file with uneven/unbalanced elements/fields, it means there is `</>` but not `<>`. For example (for simplicity, only copied part of the xml file):

```
<myTag>
    text1
    text2
<no_open/>
   text3
   text4
</myTag>
```

Now, I want to have a python programs which reads this xml file and print the tag values as follow:

```
text1
text2
text3
text4
```

However, because of this uneven element

```
<no_open/>
```

it only prints the following and ignore the rests:

```
text1
text2
```

Now, what should be the solution if I want my python ignore the **no_open** and prints the desired output.
Any help would be appreciated.

Update:

Here is my code:

```
  with open('test.xml', "r") as fp:
       tree = ElementTree.parse(fp)
       root = tree.getroot()
       release_data = root[0].text

       for tag in root.iter('tag0'):
          for c in tag:
               print c.text
```

and test.xml is:

```
<tag0>
    <myTag>
        text1
        text2
    <no_open/>
       text3
       text4
    </myTag>
</tag0>
```

Comment: Post the codes that gave you the first two texts, so we can suggest a solution on top of that instead of starting over from scratch (this way the solution can be easier to understand for you too)

Comment: Thanks @har07,  code has been added

Comment: I'm not familiar with the `xml` module, but I know in `lxml` only head text is in the `text` attribute. So if you have mixed content, further text is in `tail` attributes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try this way :

```
tree = ElementTree.parse(fp)
root = tree.getroot()

target_tag = root.find('myTag')

#collect all text nodes in <myTag> and join
result = ''.join(target_tag.itertext())

print(result)
```

**output :**

```
    text1
    text2

   text3
   text4
```